# Adding a class, then removing it and adding another

Tags: jquery, css

So I want to add a class on click, and then when it is clicked again, I want to revert it back to the previous class. How is this achieved. I have also tested it using `on()`, but no luck there either.

```js
$('.red').click(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('red').addClass('blue');
});

$('.blue').click(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('blue').addClass('red');
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="red">test click</a>
```

You can run the code **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/swnc3kg4/1/)**

How can I change the class back? It shows in the Dom, but not in the front end.

Comment: `toggleClass` is your friend [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swnc3kg4/2/)

Comment: You need to use event delegation here. Your `$('.blue')` at the time of execution cannot find an element with class `.blue` and so, no event handler is being created. You need to use `$(document).on('click', '.blue', function() { ...`

Answer (score 3):

1. Use `.toggleClass()`
2. Since button are having dynamic class use `.on()` for dynamically added elements

```js
$(document).on('click', '.red', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('red blue');
});

$(document).on('click', '.blue', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('red blue');
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="red">test click</a>
```

Comment: Concise solution that lacks to explain what needs to be changed and for what reason. Your use of toggleClass is not the main change.

Comment: Also this answer a little bit misleading, no need to use `toggleClass` twice! like the next answer, use it once to toggle `blue`

Comment: @Pedram next answer is wrong compare to this answer but its me again

Comment: i agree, the other answer is wrong and this is the right approach

Comment: Why? you can achieve this with single `toggleClass` , why used twice, please explain with an update, interesting to know. Both are same result.

Comment: @Pedram he want to remove/add two classes and not only one

Comment: @Pedram Also, using a single toggleClass for .blue only would make the code depend on the order of CSS rules - which is bad practice.

Comment: I dunno but it's already has `class="red"` so with a simple `toggleClass` you can add `blue` then remove it. But it's up to OP. *Side note* down vote is not mine.

Comment: Thanks, I had considered using on(), and even tested it, but for some reason I only did it for clicking on the blue class, and had had forgotten to do it for the red class.

Answer (score 0):

For newly created elements or classes, `.click` as you used will not work. You have to use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method in the following way :

```
$(document).on('click','.red', function(){

                $(this).removeClass('red').addClass('blue');
            });


 $(document).on('click','.blue', function(){

                $(this).removeClass('blue').addClass('red');
            });
```